# Defining modules in GWT with non-default source directories

Tags: gwt

Let's say that I want to define a module "Pair" in com.mycompany.common such that the source is located in com.mycompany.common (and not com.mycompany.common.client).  How would I do this? Alternatively, let's say that I have the flexibility of defining the module "Pair" in com.mycompany instead while still having the source in com.mycompany.common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a quick search on google, I found the answer myself.  One can add a source path tag to the module xml file to define the source directory instead of leaving it to the default "client."  For example, Pair.gwt.xml would look something like this:

```
<module>
  ...
  <source path="."/>
  ...
</module>
```

... if we wanted the gwt.xml file to be in the same directory as the source.

But when compiling this module, we get a "Non-canonical source package: ./" warning.  Is this ok to ignore?

Comment: No, it's NOT ok to ignore it. If it works for you it's by pure luck and thus incorrect. To achieve your goal you would do <source path=""/>